# Golang select and locks

Tags: go

Here's some code I've been playing with:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    channel := make(chan int)

    flag := false

    go func() {
        for {
            channel <- 1
        }
    }()

    for {
        select {
        case <-channel:
            fmt.Println(flag)

            if !flag {
                flag = true
                break
            }

            fmt.Println(flag)
        }
    }
}
```

I would expect at least one `false` in there but when I execute the code I only get `true`s. Can someone explain why please?

I'm sure it has something to do with locks but when I try to wrap the `case` content around a lock I get a `false` (finally!) but then `fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!`:

```
for {
    select {
    case <-channel:
        mutex.Lock()
        fmt.Println(flag)

        if !flag {
            flag = true
            break
        }

        fmt.Println(flag)
        mutex.Unlock()
    default:
        // no communication
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you do not get a `false` somewhere at the top of the output? I certainly do (go1.10.3 linux/amd64). It's just there is only one false, the very first one. Maybe you just miss it given all the `true`'s printed below it in huge quantities? And having a deadlock helps - since it stops printing after the first iteration

Comment: Why you are having a deadlock, is because your `break`. so `mutex.Unlock()` is never execuated. Also note that `break` breaks the `select`, not the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason to warp `flag` with a Mutex since the code around it is not concurrent.

you can check your code here https://play.golang.org/p/OJue5lcIZlw it does print the first `false`.

as for why you're getting that error as [leaf bebop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9143962/leaf-bebop) said because your breaking the code you run into a deadlock for trying to lock on a locked mutex.

you could use `defer mutex.Unlock()`
or unlock before `break` to solve that.

Comment: As dvk said I missed the first `false` because `true` gets printed a lot and my console does not allow infinite scrolling so I was missing it! Thanks for your answer.

Comment: No problem. Limiting the output to only 10 results like to playground code in my answer can help you produce more readable output next time. (Or even writing logs to files.) easy as `go run main.go > out.txt`